# How do I remove Ubuntu to install Windows?

Tags: windows

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my computer but I can't uninstall it. At the time of installation, I chose to remove Windows accidentally and then it just changed the whole computer to Ubuntu.

Now I want to remove Ubuntu. I have got my recovery disk for Windows 8, but when I put the disk Ubuntu cant run DVD's `autorun`. How can I get my Windows back?

Comment: We need some more info, such as: a) did you WIPE your previous Windows8 installation? If so the only way is to reinstall everything from the CD, but you have to put the CD in the reader, THEN reboot (sometime you have to press F8) b) if not it might be able (but somewhat complicated) to erase ubuntu and reset everything. Regards, Marcello

Answer (score 0):

In order to reinstall Windows, you must boot directly from the stick without launching Ubuntu at all. Do you know what this means or do you need further explanations? Your style of writing is somewhat incomprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

Put the CD in your DVD-drive, restart the computer and pay close attention to which button you need to press to have **boot selection menu** (usually F10 or F12)

Choose **boot from CD/DVD**

Mind you, you will not get your files back if you formatted/changed partitions.

Comment: The Cd does not show up in Boot selection menu when I press f7 at the begining